# Audio recorder error, when screen rotate

Tags: java, android

Good afeternoon

First of all, this is my first android project.

In my project I have an audio recorder and it works fine, the problem is when I switch the screen rotation gives an error and the app turns off.

```
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Error appears when Android Studio reads the line **recorder.start()**, after rotating the screen.

The error description is **Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.duarte.mediaplayerandroid/com.example.duarte.mediaplayerandroid.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.**

Comment: Sounds like you want to move the recorder off the UI thread.

Comment: I instantiate a recorder within the activity of the interface, maybe I should move to a separate class

Answer (score 0):

To handle screen rotation, Add (Override) the method `onConfigurationChanged()` in your `Activity` . As you just want to avoid config. changes,don't put any code into it. Following is the example:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
     //Nothing here...
}
```

Comment: Yes a did, and in onCreate method i get the variables back, but the error continue .